# New image size option not showing

Tags: images

I want to add a new image size option to the contents image editor. The code below is what I currently have but for some reason I am not seeing the option (as shown in the image below) in the editor. I am using WordPress Version 4.6.1. What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
    add_image_size( 'activity-image', 300, 300, array( 'center', 'center' ) );

    // Add new image sizes to post or page editor
    function new_image_sizes($sizes) {
        return array_merge( $sizes, array(
            'activity-image' => __( 'Activity Image' ),
        ) );
    }
    add_filter('image_size_names_chooser', 'new_image_sizes');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to register the image size first using [`add_image_size()`](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-additional-image-sizes-in-wordpress/), for example:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cyb_add_image_sizes' );
function cyb_add_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'my-image-size-name', 120, 120, true );
}
```

Then, you can use the `image_size_names_choose` filter (you have misspelled it with `image_size_names_chooser`):

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'rudr_new_image_sizes' );
function rudr_new_image_sizes( $sizes ) {

    $addsizes = array(
        "my-image-size-name" => 'Misha size'
    );

    $newsizes = array_merge( $sizes, $addsizes );

    return $newsizes;

}
```

Comment: I have added the image size like you said and it crops when I use it in a template. The only problem is that the option does not show up in the editor. I want to be able to select it in the attachment display settings like you can with the thumbnail size option.

Comment: The code I posted in my answer **is working as it**; have you tested it?. And please please please, if you have code that is not included in the question (like the code to add the image), [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/241353/edit) and include the code; this way we won't need to *guess* what you have done and what not.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it. Okay, I will edit to show what I have now.

Comment: My bad for that extra "r". I have tried it before without it as I was researching, trying out different pieces of code but nothing works. I just tested now to double check and still only see the default size options.

Comment: Do you mean that the code in the answer dosen't work for you? Strange, I've tested it and it works here.

Comment: Yes, I mean that it doesn't work, which definitely is strange. I also checked if I have the GD library enabled just in case, so that's not the problem. Is there ANYthing else that could be preventing this from functioning?

Comment: If you talk now about GD library .... you confuse me. Your question is about the image size selection but it seems that you are not sure if the custom image size is generated, can you check it? Is the file of the image with the custom size in your server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718776/cant-get-custom-image-sizes-to-work-in-wordpress - This post led me to check the library. Yes, its definitely there. I have it in my themes functions.php file which contains other code that works perfectly fine. When I use the_post_thumbnail('activity-image'); then it crops the post image as it should so all I need is to add that to the 'image_size_names_choose'. Apologies for confusing you.

Comment: In that case, you must have some error/issue anywhere else. Without more info, the code in the answer is all I can give you. You should start making a deeper debug, for example, you could start by deactivating all plugins and testing the code of the answer with a core theme.

Comment: I already tried deactivating all plugins yes and it made no difference. How will using a different theme help though?

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong filter function right name is [image_size_names_choose](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/image_size_names_choose)

```
Old : add_filter('image_size_names_chooser', 'new_image_sizes');

Replace : add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'new_image_sizes');
```

IF Need to display this option on old images (before applied this code) resize again using image resize plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar issue, and in my case it was the browser's adblocker addon:

I've added 3 new image sizes, and while all three were generated correctly, one specific size did not show up in the editor. It turned out that AdblockPlus was blocking images by sizes names, and the image size I had used was coincidentally used for ad banners.

There is a HUGE list of blocked images like
`-300x250.`
`-468x60.`
`-500-100.`
which is exactly Wordpress' image naming scheme.

Disable the ad blocker and everything worked fine again.